# Display all ids in database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am new to php
Following code only gives me the id of first user in database

```
$query="select* FROM users";
$result= mysqli_query($con,$query);
$results =mysqli_fetch_array($result);
print_r($results[7]);
```

what if i want to display all ids? what should i do?

Comment: Hint: It involves a loop

Comment: is `id` the only field in the table? makes no sense that `*` only returns the id of the first user. also makes no little that array index 7 is the first user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run the while loop for get all ids:

```
$query="select * FROM users";
$result= mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($results =mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $results['id'].'<br />';
}
```

The above code will output :

```
1
2
3
4
5
n
```

Comment: Need space between select and *

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a loop to fetch each row in succession:

```
$query="select * FROM users";
$result= mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['id']; // assumes 'id' is the column name
}
```

Comment: Oh GMTA, I will loose mine

Comment: Mornin' @RiggsFolly :)

Comment: Howdy there Mon ami

Comment: If the OP only needs the IDs then `SELECT id` would be better than `SELECT *`.  Only ask for what you really need when talking to a database.

Comment: True @GordonM, but since I am only making assumptions about column names I didn't want to assume all he wanted was the ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) FROM `user`;
$query="select GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) as ids FROM users"; 
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
$results=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$results[0]['ids'];`enter code here`
```

The above code will output:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7 ........